# How to exclude error message from bash string

Tags: linux, bash, grep, nvidia

I have command in my xubuntu:

```
nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp | grep '(user-xubuntu:0.0):' | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

And I have the result:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
46.
```

If I try to exclude 'libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate' :

```
nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp | grep -v 'libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate' | grep '(user-xubuntu:0.0):' | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

The result is the same. How to ignore the 'libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate' string?

Comment: `nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp 2>/dev/null` will suppress stderr and this warning

Comment: @anubhava is `2` meaning the error message?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first redirect stderr to stdout and then filter the result with grep.

```
nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp 2>&1 | grep -v 'libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate' | grep '(user-xubuntu:0.0):' | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

Comment: The `2>&1` is making the `grep -v 'libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate'` part completely unnecessary

Comment: It's not true. 2>&1 is just a redirection of stderr to stdout. In this way you can then  use grep to filter the output, since grep does not receive stderr messages from the pipe